# Error opening SQL File from TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

When I try to view a .sql file from Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio 2012 (TFS 2012) I get the following error message:

> TF10187: Could not open document
>
> FilePath\FileName
>
> User canceled out of save dialog

[image: Error Message]

It's only happening for SQL files. The file does exist in the TFSTemp folder and I can double click and open it from there. What do I need to change to fix this error message?

Comment: Should have added the path is in AppData\Local\Temp only because I don't have the file locally. The same error appears when I do have the file locally but the path becomes c:\workspaces\Greg.Dodd\...

Comment: try uninstalling add-ins, one by one. and can you reproduce this on another PC?

Comment: Thanks. Uninstalled Redgate and then got an error message for SQL Data Tools. Re-installed data tools and it all works now. If you want to make that an answer then I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to uninstall Redgate and then re-install the data tools.  This is probably because an add-in was trying to grab the .SQL files and do something with them that VS wasn't expecting.

Comment: I don't have Redgate installed and I get the same error when trying to open SQL scripts in VS2012. What would the fix/workaround be?

Answer (score 4):

Install SQL Server Data Tools - September 2013 update things will be fine. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015

Answer (score 2):

For us, this seems to be linked to a .NET Framework 4.6 upgrade and is not limited to SQL files. Users have issues opening files from Source Control Explorer and Solution Explorer.

[image: Opening from Source Control Explorer]
[image: Opening from Solution]

1. Delete the contents from the following folders:

   C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation

   C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio

   C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
2. The first step fixed it in my case, but you can try this if it doesn't: Navigate to the Visual Studio IDE folder in command prompt or windows explorer and Run the following command "devenv /resetuserdata". Ie: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE. To minimize the potential loss of the user’s personal environment, you should consider creating a backup using the Export Settings wizard, and the Import Settings wizard to restore the settings if and when needed.

Note: The side effects of running the /resetuserdata option is that any customizations will have to be reconfigured (ie: TFS server and proxy settings) as well as many, if not all, Visual Studio extensions have to be re-installed.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx

Comment: Please provide a full answer to the question, not just a link. The link might get invalid over time.